# cannot get typeof(item) dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor

I am working with Blazor and i cannot get dynamically typeof(item)

This is my code which is working because i staticlly pass value:

```
     <EditForm Model="@GalleryItem" style="text-align:center;">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" @onclick="@(()=>Accept(item.Id,"DarknetGalleryEntity"))">Accept</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" @onclick="@(()=>Deny(item.Id,"DarknetGalleryEntity"))">Reject</button>
</EditForm>
```

This is not working code i would want:

```
    <EditForm Model="@GalleryItem" style="text-align:center;">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" @onclick="@(()=>Accept(item.Id,typeof(@item)))">Accept</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" @onclick="@(() =>Deny(item.Id,typeof(@item)))">Reject</button>
</EditForm>
```

This is whole snippet:

```
<div class="collapse" id="mediaCollapse">
    <div class="card card-body">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <center><b>Not approved images</b></center>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <center>
                    @if (Gallery!.Count() == 0)
                    {
                        <center><p class="card-body"><h1>Empty</h1></p></center>
                    }
                    else
                        @foreach (var item in Gallery!)
                        {
                            <div class="card">

                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <a target="_blank" href="/gallery/@item.ImageFileName">
                                        <img src="/gallery/@item.ImageFileName" class="responsive">
                                    </a><br/>
                                    <EditForm Model="@GalleryItem" style="text-align:center;">
                                       <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" @onclick="@(() => Accept(item.Id,typeof(@item)))">Accept</button>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" @onclick="@(() => Deny(item.Id,typeof(@item)))">Reject</button>
                                    </EditForm>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        }
                </center>
            </div><br />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Wonder how i can do it dynamically because i have been always using typeof(@item).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed that simply. I used .GetType method.. but typeof() still not working but i can close this thread.

```
                                <EditForm Model="@Post" style="text-align:center;">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" @onclick="@(() => Accept(post.Id,post.GetType()))">Accept</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" @onclick="@(() => Deny(post.Id,post.GetType()))">Reject</button>
                                </EditForm>
```